# IN PHP , how to have datagrid or gridview

Tags: php, html, ajax, dhtml

How do select row in table ?? suppose table has ID and Name 
if I select first row and middle row and click on submit button, How to display selected values ?

Comment: Are you currently using a PHP framework or just freeballing it?

Comment: Not sure either to use PHP or Javascript to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use SDTable.com. There is an simple API which you can attach to your table and get out an id form selected row. Something like:

$SDT(1).SetSelectionTrigger(myfunc);
function myfunc(id, row) {
  alert(id);
  // do something
}

You generate SDT code with an easy drag&drop interface and everything is done in minutes...
Works just great for me

Answer (score 0):

Hey! Check out [Ext.js](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/). It has a data grid component. It's not simple to use but it has many many features.